# Enabling function to take different sets of arguments

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

In js, how do you create a function that can take differing sets of arguments?

(Or do you have to create a new function with a different identifier for each set of arguments?)

Example:

Argument set 1: `(0, 4, ‘purple')`

Argument set 2: `(‘purple’, true, [‘foo’, ’bar’])`

I want my function to handle [int, int, str] (Argument set 1) differently than [str, bool, array] (Argument set 2). Do I have to use `if` statements and `typeof`?

Comment: You could use if statements inside the function body and expect but one argument (an object holding possibly key a, or key b, or key c), but why not write two functions?

Comment: Because some functionality will be shared, once the arguments have been decoded. (Think of a class with multiple constructors.)

Comment: Your desired signatures are dissimilar to the point that that you'll probably end up creating an anti-pattern. I would recommend either different functions or consider if you could change to a common signature, e.g. Jethro's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest limiting the argument list to only one argument, being an object that could or could not hold certain key/value pairs.

```
function allKindsOfInput(myObject)
{
   if (myObject.color)
   {
       // do stuff with color
   }
   if (myObject.settings)
   {
       // do stuff with settings
   }
}
```

One clear interface will help keep things clean.

Comment: Even better, `let env = Object.assign({default: 'values'}, myObject);`, then use common logic

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to check the data types using typeof / instanceof,

```
var myFn = function() {
  var args = arguments;
  if (typeof args[0] === 'number') { ... }
  // or check if 2nd param is array 
  if (args[2] instanceof Array) { ... }
  // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use parameters as object.

```
function paintCar(settings)
{
    defaults = {
        paintTimes: 3,
        color: '#fff',
        paintWheels: false,
        preWash: true,
        useAssistant: true,
        paintBrand: 'super-paint',
        brushSize: 4
    }
    settings = settings || {}
    for (var key in defaults) {
        if (settings.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            defaults[key] = settings[key];
        }
    }
    settings = defaults;

    // do smth
}


paintCar();
paintCar({preWash: false});
paintCar({paintTimes: 2, color: '#448'});
// etc
```